# Unable to build maven project with two modules

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have the following project structure.

```
|-- module1
 |   `-- pom.xml
 `-- module2
     `-- pom.xml
```

I want to build module2 jar and it should contain module1's jar. In the pom.xml of module 2 , I have added module1 as a dependency. But even after providing relativePath, it is unable to build module1.The error I get is, "The POM for com.abc.xyz:module1:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available" . I tried the following. But it did
not work. Please help to resolve this issue.

```
<project>  
     <parent>
    <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../module2/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: You have to have a pom.xml in the level above modul1/module1 which contains the list of modules...(as an example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee)